# Using AM, GM, HM, and RMS.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the maximum $p$ such that $2x^4y^2 + 9y^4z^2 + 12z^4x^2 - px^2y^2z^2$ is always nonnegative for all $x$, $y$, and $z$ real.

I get this $\frac{2x^4y^2 + 9y^4z^2 + 12z^4x^2 }{3} \ge \sqrt[3]{216x^6y^6z^6}$ which simplifies to $\frac{2x^4y^2 + 9y^4z^2 + 12z^4x^2 }{3} \ge 6x^2y^2z^2$, so wouldnt p be 6? But it's wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $A,B,C > 0$ with $ABC = n^3,$ also $r,s,t > 0$ with $rst = 1,$ I get
$$ Ar + Bs + C t \geq 3n,  $$ at
$$ r = \frac{n}{A}, \; \;  s = \frac{n}{B}, \; \; t = \frac{n}{C}.  $$
That is, the minimum dot product occurs where
$$ Ar = Bs = Ct. $$ Maybe you have some inequality that allows you to recover this fact.

This is relevant if you divide your function through by $x^2 y^2 z^2.$

Comment: yeah thanks I was able to solve it :)