# Find the maximum $p$ such that $2x^4y^2 + 9y^4z^2 + 12z^4x^2 - px^2y^2z^2$ is always nonnegative for all $x$, $y$, and $z$ real.

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality

Find the maximum $p$ such that $2x^4y^2 + 9y^4z^2 + 12z^4x^2 - px^2y^2z^2$ is always nonnegative for all $x$, $y$, and $z$ real.

I have to solve this using some inequalities such as AM or GM, but I don't know how.  Solutions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Call that function $f$, notice that $f(\alpha x,\alpha y,\alpha z)=\alpha(x,y,z)$ for all $\alpha>0$ and $x,y,z\in \mathbb R$. So you only need to make sure that $f$ is non-negative on the unit sphere. So now you just need to minimize the function of the unit sphere (a compact set) with lagrange multipliers and figure out for which values of $p$ the minimum is non-negative.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937830/using-am-gm-hm-qm-and-rms/1937866#1937866

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simplify this into

$$2a^2b+9b^2c+12c^2a \geq pabc$$

for $a,b,c\geq 0$.Letting $a=3k,b=2m,c=n$ yields

$$36(k^2m+m^2n+n^2k) \geq (6p)kmn$$

$$k^2m+m^2n+n^2k \geq \left(\frac{p}{6}\right)kmn$$

We now use AM-GM on $k^2m, m^2n, n^2k$ to get that

$$\frac{k^2m+m^2n+n^2k}{3} \geq \left(k^3m^3n^3\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

$$k^2m+m^2n+n^2k \geq 3kmn$$

So we know that this is true for all $p\leq 18$. In addition, taking $k=m=n$ makes the inequality an equality, so any $p>18$ fails. Thus we have that $p=18$ is the maximum.